# Create userlist page using Django formsets and display profile image in userlist page

Tags: django

I am just beginner to python and Django
Trying to create userlist page using Django formsets and display profile image in userlist page. Not seeing image field in my formset.

```
Models – User  (from django.contrib.auth.models)


models.py

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    # def save(self):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # super().save()
        super(Profile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (200,200)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)


forms.py
class UserListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['image','username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Views.py
def userlist(request):
    UserFormSet = modelformset_factory(User,form=UserListForm, extra = 0)
    userlist_form = UserFormSet(queryset=User.objects.select_related('profile'))
    context = {'userlist_form': userlist_form}
    return render(request, 'webapp/user_list.html', context)


user_list.html
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class = "content-section">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom, mb-1 ">User Info</legend>
                <table id = "usertab" >
                    {% for form in userlist_form %}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th> <label for="id_image"> Image </label> </th>
                                  <th> <label for="id_username"> User Name </label> </th>
                                  <th> <label for="id_first_name"> First Name </label></th>
                                  <th> <label for="id_last_name"> Last  Name </label></th>
                                  <th> <label for="id_email"> Email Address  </label></th>
                                  <th> <label for="id_is_staff"> Staff  </label> </th>
                                  <th> <label for="id_is_active"> Active  </label> </th>
                                  <th> <label for="id_is_superuser"> Super User  </label> </th>
                                  <th> <label for="id_date_joined"> Joined On  </label></th>
                                  <th >  <label> User Posts</label></th>
                                  <th colspan = "2" >  <label> &nbsp;Actions</label></th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>

                        {% endif %}
                        <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row">
                          <td>  <img class="rounded-circle article-img "src="{{ form.image.url }}"> </td>
<!--                          <td> {{form.image.value}}</td>-->
                          <td><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'user-detail' form.username.value %}">{{form.username.value}}</a></td>
                          <td> {{form.first_name.value}}</td>
                          <td> {{form.last_name.value}}</td>
                          <td> {{form.email.value}}</td>
                          <td> {{form.is_staff.value}}</td>
                          <td> {{form.is_active.value}}</td>
                          <td> {{form.is_superuser.value}}</td>
                          <td> {{form.date_joined.value|date:"F d, Y"}}</td>
                          <td><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'user-posts' form.username.value %}">View Posts</a></td>
                          <td> <a class="article-title" href="{% url 'user-detail' form.username.value %}"> Edit </a> </td>
                          <td> <a class="article-title" href="{% url 'user-delete' form.username.value %}"> Delete </a> </td>

                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Want to know how to display image from related table (profile) in userlist. How to pass User profile image to formset and display in html. Please help me.